# added iOS UDID isnt accepted

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning, portal, udid

I have a iOS application that is being evaluated by test persons and testflight, I have added some more UDID to the 2 certificates using the provisioning portal, I then marked them to be included in the certificate and downloaded them to my mac. Then I deleted the ones I had in my orginizer and double clicked the new downloaded certificates. In Xcode I then run "Archive" and submited the new app to testflight. But when the users with the newly added UDID try to install the app to their iPad's they can't beacuse the UDID isn't accepted.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You probably have to clean up some old certificates in the Keychain, and double check that the ones you choose in Xcode to compile the ad-hoc app are corrects. I used to have this kind of problem.

Comment: hmm, as far as I can tell I use the correct certificates.. there is also an option to select "automatic", should I use that one instead?